# How to detect external database changes from Flask API

Tags: flask, socket.io, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm writing an API in Flask, and part of this API will also be sending SocketIO events for frontend clients. But since this API will read from a table that is also updated by an external application I would need a mechanism to detect database changes when they occur and if needed then send events to clients so they will update their statuses. I wanted to use SQLAlchemy events with `after_update` events but I then learned they are ORM events and can't be used for external changes. So I want to know if there is any mechanism or tool that I could use for this purpose. Maybe SQL trigger that would execute some script that would then send an event to Flask or a timer that would read the database periodically and send the updates. The database I'm using is MariaDB/MySQL.

I'll be gratefull for all advices :)

Answer (score 0):

My way may not be the best but you could, instead of using the sqlite write functions, make your own using them
example:

```py
def dbWrite(data, params=None):
   # db code here for writing
   written = True
   # or you could just write all the code that you were going to do on the update right here
```

Sorry if my way isnt the most intelligent

Comment: Well my problem is that I'm not the one who is writing in the database, so I can't use your solution. If all the updates would happen inside my application I could just use SQLAlchemy ORM events :)